# Firebase onNewToken method can not resolve

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I extend my service class to FirebaseMessagingService but this class does not override onNewToken() or onTokenRefresh() methods.

It only overrides onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage), onDeletedMessages(), onMessageSent(s:String),onSendError(s:String, e:Exception) and handleIntent(intent:Intent) methods.

Comment: And what is the question? you can override onNewToken in a FirebaseMessagingService to receive the token.

Comment: As I said above, It does not let me override onNewToken() method. I mean, it does not exist

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using old version of firebase messaging library,
Use latest version of firebase messaging

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.0'
```

If still not working share your app gradle code.

Comment: I already implemented that dependency. My app see firebase messaging classes but can not override onNewToken method

Answer (score 0):

if you did add dependency

extended `FirebaseMessagingService`

imported from `import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;`

and this can not be overrided

kotlin

`override fun onNewToken(token: String)`

or

java

```
  @Override
    public void onNewToken(@NonNull String s) {
```

then try invalidating and restarting Android studio because it has to work

Comment: Unfortunately it does resolve that method. I tried invalidating and restarting Android Studio but the result is same...